# Как убрать лишний задний фон в заголовке html

Tags: html, css

Хочу поставить задний фон на заголовок через `<style>`. Но он ставится на всю строку заголовка. А мне нужно, чтобы он был лишь около текста.

Как я могу это сделать? Абсолютно не разбираюсь в html, ибо пишу бэкенд. Прошу подробно объяснить ваше решение, если таковое вообще есть.

Вот тот самый заголовок из основного кода:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<style> 
.hh1{ border-radius: 7px;
  color: white;
  background: #f10000;
  padding: 1px;
  border: none;
}
</style>
<h1 class="hh1" ><font size="4" face="Tahoma">{{ title }}</font></h1>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По умолчанию у блоков width равно auto. Это значение растягивает блок на всю ширину. Я установил width равным fit-content.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <style>
    .hh1 {
      border-radius: 7px;
      color: white;
      background: #f10000;
      padding: 1px;
      border: none;
      width: fit-content;
    }
  </style>
  <h1 class="hh1">
    <font size="4" face="Tahoma">{{ title }}</font>
  </h1>
</head>

<body>

</body>

</html>
```